# ServiceStack session lifetime is increased on heartbeat

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

I have a Service with a `ServerEventsFeature`. I'm using a `ServerEventsClient` which by default sends heartbeats to the service. As far as I know ServiceStack doesn't support sliding expiration from the box, but session lifetime is refreshed after every heartbeat. Is this how it should be and are there any ways to control that? I've tested it by setting `SessionExpiry` to 30s and `HeartbeatInterval` to 20s - the app sends multiple (10+) heartbeats w\o any problems. In addition, if client app crashes and force closes - the session will be "alive" in the server sessions list until I try to use it, is there a way to drop it earlier?

Example:

1. start the server
2. launch client 1

execute

```
var sessionPattern = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>("");
var sessionKeys = Cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();
var allSessions = Cache.GetAll<IAuthSession>(sessionKeys);
```

the results count is 1

3. launch client 2 and 3
4. drop client 1 through force shutdown (no logout calls)
5. execute the same code again - results count is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Server Events subscription doesn't have any impact on a Users Session.

A Users Session is created after a user successfully authenticates and is destroyed when they **explicitly logout** or when the **session expiry elapses**.

A Server Events subscription is just a reference to a users long-lived HTTP Connection to the SSE `/event-stream`, it's only relation to a Users Session is that the subscription may be that of an authenticated user.

But the life-cycle of a Users Session (which is just a AuthUserSession POCO persisted in the registered `ICacheClient`) is not affected by a Server Events subscription since it never re-saves the Users Session, so never changes the Session Expiry.

Comment: Then it looks like i'm coding something wrong. Thank you, i will make additional tests